# ECS + ZooKeeper / Kafka - would it work?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, amazon-ecs

I've never used ZooKeeper/Kafka before, so if there's something that I'm stating is wrong, please feel free to correct.

Would it be a good idea to have a ZooKeeper/Kafka cluster scale up/down using AWS ECS? I'm not particularly sure how this is done as there doesn't seem to be a lot of information coupling the two together, so I'm starting to feel like it's not something I should be doing.

There doesn't SEEM to be a way to auto-add zookeeper replicas to a cluster, and the same seems to be true for Kafka (unless MirrorMaker is used).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ZooKeeper** can be managed by [Exhibitor](https://github.com/soabase/exhibitor) for [automatic instance management](https://github.com/soabase/exhibitor/wiki/Automatic-Instance-Management), using a [shared config](https://github.com/soabase/exhibitor/wiki/Shared-Configuration) location. Combine this into a **Docker** image, with **Amazon S3** as the backend option, and you should be good to go.

**Kafka** is a bit more complicated, as each node needs a unique `broker.id` and you need to manage those with failure and node replacement in mind. Additionally, you need to rebalance topic partitions, when a new `broker.id` is added to the set, or removed from it (i.e when you scale in or out). I highly recommend [this](http://tech.gc.com/scaling-with-kafka/) blog post on the subject of `broker.id` management in an autoscaling group.

Note that both issues are related to automatic **Kafka** scaling, not using **Amazon ECS** per se. Deploying **Kafka** with some restrictions in a **Docker** container on **Amazon ECS** should be fairly straightforward.

I'm not sure how **MirrorMaker** would fit into your scenario, but keep in mind, that this is just another consumer - it has nothing to do with cluster management.

Comment: How would any existing/new Kafka instances know of all the ZooKeepers addresses?

Comment: @Ben: I would suggest researching **service discovery** in this context as there are many options to build this. We're currently using a local `haproxy` instance, but you could probably spawn a regular ELB as well.

Comment: Isn't haproxy more of a load balancing solution? I was more hoping for a dynamic service discovery solution for Kafka (such that if ZooKeeper instances are added/removed, it will dynamically readjust to such settings).

Comment: The "dynamic" part is essentially about keeping some access point *in sync* with the current cluster state - you'll need to provide this yourself as it's not within Kafka's responsibilities to "manage" the ZooKeeper ensemble ([example](https://seanmcgary.com/posts/automatically-scale-haproxy-with-confd-and-etcd)).

Comment: @Ben did you ever resolve this? and how did you handle the ADVERTISED_HOST? Also what image did you use? https://github.com/spotify/docker-kafka ?